# How to disable Keycloak Account client but keeping Account Rest API?

Tags: keycloak

I need to block user access to Keycloak Account client (**/auth/realms/[MYREALM]/account**) but I need the Rest API provided by this client.

I'm using Keycloak 4.1.0. I have tried to disable account client through keycloak admin panel (**/auth/admin/master/console/#/realms/[MYREALM]/clients**), but if I disable this client, Account Rest API is no longer working.

There is an Apache in front of this Keycloak and I guess I could filter requests using Apache, but I'm not allowed to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove the client role 'manage_account' for client 'account'. [image]

Go to realm > Configure > Roles > Default Roles > Client Roles > Select 'account' > remove 'manage-account'

Comment: Can it be done using REST API?

Comment: @Sirish, if you'd like to create a script to automate it, you can use the KC [AdminCLI](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-documentation/blob/main/server_admin/topics/admin-cli.adoc). Check the API calls in your browser's developer tools when you perform the operation from the UI and try to reproduce that with the AdminCLI tool.